# Mockito mocked class has zero invocation on its method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

My code is calling a third party API to get a file record, this is how I call it:

```
Vendor vendor = new Vendor();
Object record = vendor.getRecord("recordId");
```

In my junit, I am trying to do:

```
Vendor vendorMock = mock(Vendor.class);
Mockito.when(vendorMock.getRecord("recordId")).thenReturn(record);
// call real method here
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post(someurl).content(somecontent).contentType(contentType))
                         .andDo(print())
                         .andExpect(status().isAccepted())
                         .andReturn();

// failed at verify here
Mockito.verify(vendorMock, times(1)).getRecord(ArgumentMatchers.any(String.class));
```

I am getting an error on the `Mockito.verify`, saying `there were zero interactions with this mock`.  Not sure what I did wrong.  Will appreciate it if someone can point out the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Mockito doesn't mock a class. It creates a mock **object**. `vendorMock`will return  the record you told it to return. But all the other instances of Vendor won't. You're supposed to inject this mock dependency into the bean you're testing. That's what DI is useful for.

Comment: Further to the comment above, you need your `vendor` variable to refer to a mocked object.  However, you are creating that object using `new`, which means Mockito can't get the mock instance into that variable.  So depending on the actual circumstances of your code, either inject the `vendor`, or you'll have to use PowerMockito to mock the construction (see https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects )

Comment: Thank you guys.  Yeah, the third party provider asked us to use the "new" to create an object while using their API.  And the `vendor` is a local variable, so what do you mean by "inject the `vendor`"

Comment: Since it's a local variable, then yes, "inject" doesn't apply.